# Babel 7.0 and webpack fail

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to run babel

npx webpack -p --env production && babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps inline

As i see the error show up in the later part of the command.

The error that i get after running the command:

```
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.25.0". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.
at throwVersionError (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/Desktop/project4/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
at Object.assertVersion (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/Desktop/project4/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
at _default (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/Desktop/project4/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/index.js:35:7)
at /mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/Desktop/project4/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
at Function.memoisePluginContainer (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:113:13)
at Function.normalisePlugin (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:146:32)
at /mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalisePlugins (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
at OptionManager.init (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
at File.initOptions (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
at new File (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
at Pipeline.transform (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
at transform (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:50:22)
at Object.compile (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:59:12)
at write (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/dir.js:21:21)
at handleFile (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/dir.js:43:7)
at /mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/dir.js:61:9
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at handle (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/dir.js:59:29)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/dir.js:69:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Arkadiy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/index.js:129:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
```

This is my config.js information:

DevDependencies :

```
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"eslint": "^5.9.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.27.2",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
"flow-bin": "^0.82.0",
"flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"jest-cli": "^23.6.0",
```

Dependencies:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"webpack": "^4.25.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
```

Webpack config

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: 'babel-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm cache clean` and reinstalling using `npm install`, then rebuilding.

Comment: Gives error 
```npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.```

Comment: You might try `npm cache clean --force`, but proceed at your own risk. Although, I'm not sure of any major implications if you do.